# WebApi is not Working in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am New in Asp.Net and tried to develop a small Web API in learning process.

> WebApiConfig.cs

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

> TopicsController.cs

```
namespace MessageBoard.Controllers
{
    public class TopicsController : ApiController
    {
        private IMessageBoardRepository _repo;

        public TopicsController(IMessageBoardRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Topic> Get()
        {

            var topics = _repo.GetTopics()
                            .OrderByDescending(t => t.Created)
                            .Take(25)
                            .ToList();
            return topics;
        }
    }
}
```

Actually i am watching PluralSight tutorials.

```
http://localhost:50031/api/v1/topics
```

this Url is not working in Browser not in Fiddler 4.

all references are added. i have also done Build Solution but its not working and their is no error showing in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One last step to enable Web Api which looks like you're missing is enabling Web API in the Global.asax file by adding the following line of code to the `Application_Start()` method:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

Also, please don't use the port number from the PluralSight tutorial.You need to run the web application project from your instance of Visual Studio and when it opens up in the browser you will see which port is assigned to **YOUR** api service.So if you see that it assigned port 12345 for example you would call the following URL to access the service action:

```
http://localhost:12345/api/v1/topics
```

Comment: Thank you for Answer but Sir its Not working in My Case.

Comment: Have a look the update please.Are you running the web api project in Visual Studio and are you using the right port when making the call?

Comment: Its working by Adding "GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);" Under "AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();" 
Thanks Alot sir for giving me directions

Answer (score 1):

Add attribute routing to controller

```
[Route("api/v1/topics")]
public IEnumerable<Topic> Get()
    {

        var topics = _repo.GetTopics()
                        .OrderByDescending(t => t.Created)
                        .Take(25)
                        .ToList();
        return topics;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for Answer but Sir its Not working in My Case.

Comment: if not then problem is somewhere else not in routing

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for giving me Your Precious Time.